# Oracle SQL developer headless

Tags: sql, oracle, headless

I am trying to use SQL on a server so that I can import dmp files. I've installed Oracle SQL developer. I can't use the GUI obviously since I am connecting to the server via ssh, I need to do everything headless - not sure how to proceed now.

Is sqlcli what I will need to use? Is SQL developer even made for headless operations? Thanks for a push in the right direction, I can find hardly anything about this topic.

Comment: A "dmp file" would normally be something that was generated using the Oracle export utility (classic or DataPump).  If that is what you have, is there a reason that you want to use SQL Developer rather than just calling `imp` or `impdp` directly on the command line?

Comment: I have the dmp on my local machine. However I need to be able to use the dmp file to create the schema on a server which doesn't have any SQL installation on it yet.

Comment: Then I'm really confused.  An export cannot be used to create a database or to install the database software.  The database software would need to be installed on the server and a database would need to have been created before you could import the export file to create the schema.  If "doesn't have any SQL installation" means that the server doesn't even have the Oracle database software installed, you cannot get there from here.  You'd need to install the database software and create a database first regardless of what tool you use to import the file.

Comment: Yes that's where I'm stuck. I tried installing SQL developer on the server, but cannot figure out how to use it on the command line. The script 'sqlcli', which I assume is meant for just that, doesn't work due to Java Errors. All I am wondering is if SQL developer is even meant for headless operations, such as creating a database and then importing a dmp file from the command line or if I need to look for a different SQL installation

Comment: You can't install the database software using SQL Developer whether it is headless or in full GUI mode.  I seriously doubt that you can create a database from SQL Developer but that would at least theoretically be possible.  You'd need to download the full database installer which can be run in silent mode.  You would install the software and create the database as part of that.  Once you've done that, you can use the command-line import utility to import your export file.